# How can i reproduce such a chart using ChartJs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm currently working on a web application that uses Highcharts & Highstock to generate charts. For some reasons, I was asked to replace these librairies, and I chose to use ChartJs to do so. However, I have no idea how to reproduce the following chart using Chartjs, since it has to be done using only one canvas/chart.
[image]

First of all, I have managed to do [this](https://codepen.io/Frixionder/pen/zYyEyXq) using the stacked property on the X axis, such as :

```js
x: {
  type: "time",
  position: 'top',
  ticks: {
    major:{
      enabled: true
    },
    minRotation: 0,
    maxRotation: 0,
    source:'data'
  },
  time: {
    unit: 'day'
  },
  stacked: true
},
```

*Here's an image in case you don't want to open the link*
[image]

As you can see, the bars are stacked on top on each other, which is not exactly what I am trying to achieve.

I have also tried to use one X axis per dataset. Sadly, it didn't work and I ended up with this:

[image]
[*Code available here*](https://codepen.io/Frixionder/pen/qBLPgdX)

Now I feel kind of stuck since I don't know what else I can do.

***TL;DR : I have to reproduce the chart in the first image using Chartjs***